# queue stops and no longer reads the remaining messages

Tags: rabbitmq, apache-camel

I have a simple route that reads a message and a bean that processes it, but if the bean takes too long to process it, the queue stops and no longer reads the remaining messages.

Is there any setting I can use to avoid this?

Comment: Can you post more information? what does the logs say?

Comment: One possible reason is consumer_timeout.  See https://www.rabbitmq.com/consumers.html#acknowledgement-timeout

Comment: @ChadKnutson is it possible to disable the timeout directly from the route? with something like .connectionTimeout(10800)

Comment: Currently the consumer_timeout can only be set at the cluster.